# Why does my PC shutdown and restart when house power goes down?

Tags: desktop-computer, low-power

Why do some computers (particularly, my computer) shut down and restart every time the house power become low? Other PCs continue to work properly with no problem.

What can the cause be?

These are the specifics for my computer.

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-P31-ES3G
- Graphics card: ATI Radeon HD5570
- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo
- Power supply: Delux ATX - 350W P4

Comment: Some power supplies have larger capacitors than others, and take longer to drain.  Get a UPS problem solved.

Comment: If you don't have a UPS and are experiencing frequent brown outs, you should adjust the bios settings on your PCs so that when they shut down initially they stay off. See Page 42 in your MB manual -http://download1.gigabyte.us/Files/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-p31-es3g_e.pdf. You want to configure it to stay off when power comes back on to avoid a brownout / reboot cycle which will damage your PC sooner or later.

Comment: Wimpy computers don't drain the power supply caps as quickly so some don't reboot on minor blips, get an Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS) so yours doesn't reboot.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply...

I was using UPS but it didn't go will with me, because i live in area that the power goes down frequency (every 5-10 min) and stay low for approximately 10 sec and that makes the UPS start beeping after few hours of using it,specially when i work on graphic card (games or design) and finally shut off...
.
so I'm trying to figure out what part i have to change in my PC to fix the problem , or if you have another solution please tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the PSU is not fit for the rest of your system. It is too old/too low power rating. Its capacitors are unable to support the load while the power is down. So change your PSU and you should be fine.

Comment: is there specific Feature in PSU should i look for it?...what you recommend?

Comment: No special features are needed. Take a look at the reviews here: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/best-psus,4229.html . Even a 450W one like the corsair in the review is more than enough, but it's recommended to be a good brand so you should have no problems on the long term. Note the general use ones (random junk brands) can be rated higher but actually be significantly worse than a good band one. Basically, you can even tell good from bad by the weight. The heavier the better.